# Method toString() issue

Tags: java, tostring

I am creating application for canteen management. I must use the overriden method toString() somewhere so i put it in the class Menu for displaying total menu price.But i can`t call the method in my main(). How can i do this ?

```
class Menu {

    private Soup soup;
    private SecondMeal second;
    private Dessert desert;

    public Menu(int soupId, int secId, int desId) {
        soup = new Soup(soupId);
        second = new SecondMeal(secId);
        desert = new Dessert(desId);
    }

    double price = soup.getPrice() + second.getPrice() + desert.getPrice();

    //here is my toString() method
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String str = "Your menu price is " + price;
        return str;
    }

}

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int soupId, secondId, desertId;

        do {
            System.out.println("Choose soup: ");
            Display.soupMenu();
            soupId = scan.nextInt();
        }
        while (soupId < 1 || soupId > 3);

        do {
            System.out.println("Choose second meal: ");
            Display.secondMenu();
            secondId = scan.nextInt();

        }
        while (secondId < 1 || secondId > 3);

        do {
            System.out.println("Choose dessert: ");
            Display.desertMenu();
            desertId = scan.nextInt();

        }
        while (desertId < 1 || desertId > 3);

        // here is the problem...
        System.out.println(Menu.toString()); // cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

    }
}
```

Comment: You've told it how to convert a Menu object to a string; now you need to create a Menu object.

Comment: You don't seem very experiences with OOP, you might want to refresh or read up on that :)

Comment: No, i`m not very expirienced with OOP :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions:

- You need to create a Menu instance in the main method in order to call methods on it. I'd start there.
- Your other classes should have `toString()` methods, including all of the food classes.
- Within Menu's `toString()` method you could then iterate through the foods ordered, calling each one's toString() method in order to build up Menu's own String that it will return.

Comment: Can you show me short example of your third point ? How should i make this iteration ?

Comment: @user2976091: not based on your current code. But assuming that all food classes extend an abstract Food class parent. Your Menu class could hold an `ArrayList<Food>` of concrete Food items, and in Menu's `toString()`, you'd use a for loop to iterate through the list, adding each food item's `toString()` result to a result String that the method then returns.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an instance of Menu and call "toString())" on that because it's not static.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this line

```
double price = soup.getPrice() + second.getPrice() + desert.getPrice();
```

will immediately fail. All instance fields are initialized before the constructor body is executed. At that point `soup`, `second` and `desert` are `null`. This will throw a `NullPointerException`. Instead, add that line at the end of your constructor.

```
double price;
...
public Menu(int soupId, int secId, int desId) {
    soup = new Soup(soupId);
    second = new SecondMeal(secId);
    desert = new Dessert(desId);
    price = soup.getPrice() + second.getPrice() + desert.getPrice();
}
```

For how to call the `toString()` method on an instance, see the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

- 1: You can't  call a non-static method in a static method like main method.
- 2: A non-static class can't call like --classname.method
- 3 You're calling should be   `new Mean（parameters）`, an object of a non-static class .

Answer (score 0):

At `System.out.println` toString should not manually call. It will call with the instance of object. Try to call like

```
 System.out.println(new Menu()); //toString will automatically call here.
```

Comment: `new Menu(int, int, int)`